# Get rows from the table using row no in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to get rows from 100-150 from my table in sql server 2008, how i can do that? Is there any way to do so? as much i search Limit keyword is available in mysql but for sql server use common table technique but i don't want to do like that is there any other way available as it is available in Mysql?

Comment: Remove the mysql tag as it's confusing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from
(select row_number() over (order by @column) as row,*  from  Table) as t
where row between 100 and 150
```

@column to be replaced by a colomn from your table witch well be used to order the result

Answer (score 0):

use sql limit

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: I want to know some thing same in SQL Server not im MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2005 and above there is a ROW_NUMBER() function.  If you need something that works for both MySQL and SQL Server though then I don't know if this is available in MySQL as I've never used it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

The example given in the linked page that seems most relevant is the following, where the results of a query are ordered by date, and then rows 50 to 60 from that result set are returned.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Comment: Row_Number returns the last entered row as like identity method do it, we are not able to give rows count e.g 100- 120 or 20-25 etc

Comment: I added an example to my answer to make it clearer.  It seems to do what you are asking for: return a specified range of rows from a select.

Answer (score 0):

Actuall, the least expensive way to do this is using top, and then row_number()

```
select *
from (select *,  row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as rownum
      from (select top 150 t.*
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where rownum >= 100
```

However, I do give you one caution.  There is no such thing as rows 100-150 in a relational table, because these are inherently unordered.  You need to specify the ordering.  For this, you need order by:

```
select *
from (select *,  row_number() over (order by <field>) as rownum
      from (select top 150 t.*
            from t
            order by <field>
           ) t
     ) t
where rownum >= 100
```